# Intuitionistic Proof of $(a \Rightarrow b) \Rightarrow (\lnot b \Rightarrow \lnot a)$

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I'm trying to prove

$$(a \Rightarrow b) \Rightarrow (\lnot b \Rightarrow \lnot a)$$

A seemingly natural way to start is by assuming the left side, as well as assuming a. This ends up proving what I want but I can't eliminate my assumption of a.

Any insight beyond a strictly mechanical derivation are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Assume $a \to b$.
2. Assume $\lnot b$.
3. Assume $a$.
4. Then $b$.
5. Then $\bot$.
6. Eliminating (3), $\lnot a$.
7. Eliminating (2), $\lnot b \to \lnot a$.
8. Eliminating (1), $(a \to b) \to (\lnot b \to \lnot a)$.

I think everything is clear up to step 5; beyond that you need a clear grasp of the notion of conditional proof. (You also need to remember that $\lnot x$ is an abbreviation for $x \to \bot$.)

Comment: That is my proof. You just repeated ;-D Eliminating steps are clear.

Comment: To be clear, by step 4 we had b and not b. From that we can prove anything. The insight is to prove absurdity so that the proof can proceed. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to recall that Nx is an abbreviation for Cx0 necessarily, though that will suffice.  You could have CCp0Np as an axiom, which isn't quite the definition.

Comment: @z5h No, the point is that $\lnot a$ is an abbreviation of $a \to \bot$, so if you want to prove $\lnot a$, you should assume $a$ and prove $\bot$; similarly, $\lnot b$ is an abbreviation of $b \to \bot$, so if you want to deduce $\bot$ from $\lnot b$, you should prove $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume "a => b" and "not b". Then "not a" because: If "a", then "b", but we assumed "not b". Contradiction, so "not a" holds.